# Control over Delphi form components destroy order

Tags: delphi

Is there any way to control the order of which a Delphi form is destroying its components?

I got AVs when the form is destroying because it is destroying a component before the other component which accesses the first component.

Currently, I have no way to avoid AVs except free the first component in **finalization** section

Comment: You need to fix your components to that they don't care about this. Further, I don't understand why `finalization` is relevant. That is when the module terminates. But the issue arises when the form is destroyed. Often the latter is triggered by the former, but not always.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The 2nd component needs to read/write data from 1st component even when destroying, So the 1st one must be there and be freed as last one. The finalization section executes after form ObDestroy, So I destroy the 1st component there.

Comment: I think it is unrealistic to expect to control the order of destruction. You should instead ask to be notified of destruction. What you are hoping for breaks the design rules of components.

Comment: I found a way to contol the order of desrruction, See my answer below

Comment: You found a way to control the order of destruction in certain cases. It is not sure if this is universal, and it is certainly relying on internals. This can be changed by the vendor. Rather ensure that you get notified when a partner control is freed and after that, don't access it anymore. That is a lot safer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to call `FreeNotification()` on the control being referenced and override the protected `Notfication()` method of your control that is referencing it.

Say you have a property that links to another component (say, a `TEdit`):

```
property EditControl: TEdit read FEdit write SetEdit;
```

Then, if your property is set to link to such a component, you tell it that you want to be notified when it is freed, by calling its `FreeNotification()` method:

```
procedure TMyControl.SetEdit(Value: TEdit);
begin
  if FEdit <> Value then
  begin
    if FEdit <> nil then
      FEdit.RemoveFreeNotification(Self); 
    FEdit := Value;
    if FEdit <> nil then
      FEdit.FreeNotification(Self); 
  end;
end;
```

This means that your `Notification()` procedure will be called when the `TEdit` is destroyed. You will have to override it:

```
protected
  procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
...

procedure TMyControl.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FEdit) then
    FEdit := nil;
end;
```

That way, you will know when you can access the `TEdit` component, and when not to anymore. If `FEdit` is `nil`, you should not access it.

Examples taken from: 
http://mc-computing.com/Languages/Delphi/ComponentNotification.html

Documentation:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FreeNotification

Comment: @Remy thanks for the correction (removing the free notification on an already existing linked component).

Answer (score -1):

I did some search and some tests and found how to control the Delphi form components destroy order.

There are two ways, at design time and at runtime:

1. At design time, Edit the form's DFM, move the first component's **object** block as first block before any other object blocks of any other components that must be freed after the first one.
2. At runtime, in form OnCreate, Change ComponentIndex property of first component to any value lower than the other components which depend on it, Say 0, this will make it last one to be freed.

Example: `FirstComp.ComponentIndex := 0;`

That's it!

As you can see, Delphi frees components in the opposite order of which they were added to the form (LIFO), But we can alter this order as I explained.

Thanks everyone for your valuable help. Appreciate it.

Comment: This is the wrong way to solve the problem. If you are content, fine. But I'm voting down so that future visitors can be warned away from such folly.

Comment: David, I'm not here to collect votes,  I'm not only learning the language but also learning stackoverflow as I'm new to this site,  I had a problem and found a solution, that works fine and solved my problem and I'm satisfied, If this solution does not work for you then this is your problem, not the solution, because it works as needed. Beside, I don't see your answer so I can compare and choose which is best for me.

Comment: @Delphine - You should be seeing an answer - which you can compare to yours if you want.

Comment: Sertac, until now, Only Rudy Velthuis, thanks to him,  presented an answer, But the solution he suggested does not let me control the order of destroying components, which is the topic question, his solution only let me know when a component is destroyed. I found a way to control the destroy order as I posted above which seems the only way, David says its wrong, bur he didn't explained why its wrong, may be because he believes that, I quote him "I think it is unrealistic to expect to control the order of destruction"

Comment: @Delphine - It's wrong because it relies on implementation detail. The solution that lets you know when a component is destroyed should solve your problem according to the explanation in the question.

Comment: Sertac, Knowing when a component is destroyed is not an answer to my question which is "How to control components destroy order?", A component that is used by other components to store their data must be destroyed after those components, Just knowing when it is destroyed is not enough, and components processed data will no longer  be saved! , and that is not accepted. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "It's wrong because it relies on implementation detail"? The ComponentIndex property is there to be used, Isn't it? but you are saying it is wrong to use it?!

Comment: Perhaps I'd rather say "it would be wrong to use this solution". What I meant is, destruction order depending on component index is not documented and therefore should not be relied upon. It may be changed at vendor's will in future versions.

Comment: You don't need to control the order of destruction. You can't ask the framework to do that. You can simply use the approach in Rudy's answer to solve your problem.

Comment: Delphi uses ComponentIndex for other purposes like iterating through components...etc. Clearly, As my tests showed,  It also uses ComponentIndex to determine the destruction order of owned components. This solution is working fine for me, ComponentIndex is a documented public WRITABLE property and has been there for many versions, Probably from the begining (I will check that out). Until someone finds a better solution I'll stick to ComponentIndex. And again, Rudy's solution does NOT provide a way to control the destruction order, it just let me know when a component is about to be destroyed,

Comment: @Delphine - If you can produce a [mcve] that uses destruction order to avoid an AV, you might consider asking a question about how can you use notification mechanism instead. Don't get offended and think that we're pushing you around. It's all just humble efforts at helping...

Comment: @David: I just did that!

Comment: Sertac, I appreciate your help and I kindly ask you to participate in answering my upcoming questions, there will be for sure, there are no learning without discussions. As for the AV itself, It can be avoided in other ways, but that AV urged me to think how to control the destruction order of a form components? So I posted the question here.